# Laravel update form only shows one id

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have a page that displays records from the database and two buttons with the addition of a new record and editing using the bootstrap modal in `Laravel 5.8`. When I add a new record to the database, everything works. The problem is when editing a record it only changes the first record because it does not transfer the remaining id it always shows only the first id. As I display the records with each button edit, I display the id of the record and everything shows correctly but after pressing the button edit does not provide the id. In the form I use the following code. source: [a link]https://github.com/page4me/transport

```
@foreach($cars as $car)
               @if(($car->status)==1)

                 <tr>
                   <td class="text-center">{{$i++}}</td>
                   <td>{{$car->rodzaj_poj}}<br /><strong> {{$car->marka}} </strong></td>
                   <td class="text-center">{{$car->nr_rej}}</td>
                   <td class="text-center">{{$car->nr_vin}}</td>
                   <td class="text-center">{{$car->dmc}} kg</td>
                   <td class="text-center">{{$car->wlasnosc}}</td>
                   <td class="text-center">wprowadzono <br />{{$car->data_wpr}} r.</td>
                   <td class="text-center" colspan="2">
                   {{$cid =$car->id}}
                    <button data-toggle="modal" data-idcar="{{$car->id}}" data-nr_rej="{{$car->nr_rej}}"  data-marka="{{$car->marka}}" data-nr_vin="{{$car->nr_vin}}" data-wlasnosc="{{$car->wlasnosc}}" data-data_wpr="{{$car->data_wpr}}" data-dmc="{{$car->dmc}}" data-rodzaj_poj="{{$car->rodzaj_poj}}" data-target="#editModal" role="button" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" alt="Edycja" ><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button>

                    <a href="#" role="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">Wycofaj</a>

                                      <!-- edit modal -->
                                <!-- Modal -->
                                  <div class="modal fade" id="editModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
                                    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg" role="document">
                                      <div class="modal-content text-left">
                                        <div class="modal-header  bg-success">
                                          <div class="card-header bg-success text-light" >
                                             Edycja pojazdu przedsiębiorcy o  -
                                               <span style="color:#000;font-size:15px;"> Nr licencji / zezwolenia:
                                                 @foreach($dok as $dk)
                                                   {{ $dk->nr_dok }}

                                               </span><span style="color: #fff;font-size:15px;">wydano dn. {{ $dk->data_wyd}}   r.</span>

                                                 @endforeach
                                            </div>
                                          <button type="button" class="close text-light" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                          </button>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-body">
                                           ID:  {{$cid =$car->id}}
                                            <!-- Form edit car -->
                                                <form method="post" action="{{ route('pojazdy.update', $cid ) }}">
                                              <div class="row">
                                                    @csrf
                                                      @method('PATCH')
                                                 <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                                                    <label for="nr_rej"><strong>Numer rejestracyjny:</strong></label>
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="nr_rej" id="nr_rej" value="{{$car->nr_rej}}"/>
                                                </div>
                                               </div>
```

It always displays only the first id even though it is displayed in the foreach loop. next to buttons edit correctly shows id and when using in `action = "{{route ('vehicle.update', $ car-> id)}}"` there is already a problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having is that you are looping on `$cars` and setting multiple elements within the dom to the same `id`.  Within that `foreach` loop, you have several items that will be overwritten many times.

For example:

```
//This SAME id will appear every time you have a new car loop
<div class="modal fade" id="editModal"/>

//This nr_rej will ONLY be the LAST nr-rej in the loop.  It will overwrite every one before it.
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="nr_rej" id="nr_rej" value="{{$car->nr_rej}}"/>
```

You can fix this in several ways.  You can add arrays to the values, you can add an actual car `id` to the dom element ids (`id=nr_rej-{{$car->id}}`), etc.  But typically, this is easiest if you load the modal via an ajax call - this way you don't have to stick modal code on the screen for every loop - just one.

Hope this helps

Comment: Sorry - didn't mean ajax necessarily - meant via a JS or Jquery call

Comment: I tried the data in the modal window to enter via jquery by downloading from the button edit everything works fine but as you wrote it changes the data of only one id

Comment: If you are using jQuery have you changed the code?  I wrote what was *broken*.  So, in particular, if you are sending via jQuery, you must change at least this: `value="{{$car->nr_rej}}"` to a value for the car id that was supplied by the button data attribute.  Make sense?

Comment: so enter in this way <input type = "text" name = "nr_rej" value = "data-nr_rej" />? or as I have by id = "nr_rej" <input type = "text" name = "nr_rej" id = "data_nr_rej" value = "" />?

Comment: No, this is really a different question.  But, if you are supplying this by jquery, you will need to use jquery to put the value in.  Something like `$("#nr_rej").val($("#yourButtonId").data('nr_rej'));`  You'll need to add your code with your own ids, and leave the id in the input, but that will work for you. But the answer to the original question of why it was only showing the last `id` is correct per my answer.

Comment: where is $ car-> id I can insert a value from the button edit data-id = "$ car-> id"? <form method = "post" action = "{{route ('vehicles.update', $ car-> id)}}"> from here is the id passed to the controller for the update function and here it gets the last record as you wrote even as Modal window has entered beyond the foreach loop

Comment: i solved this problem how you write i use only jquery and change my function in controller with 1 parameter only public function update(Request $request) $cars = \App\WykazPoj::findOrFail($request->idcar); and work corrent how i want :)